# Firebase SimpleLogin - Is there a way to create a user name and let the user login using the user name, instead of email?

Tags: firebase-security

I'm currently using the Firebase SimpleLogin with Email/Password authentication for my application but would like to let the user create a custom login name (similar in function to a Twitter handle), which can be used to authenticate the user as well, in addition to the email.

Is there a way to perform the aforementioned functionality with the Email/Password SimpleLogin or do I need to roll my own using Custom Login?

Thanks!

-Tony